# How to export digital wellbeing data to third party application

Tags: java, android, mobile-application, mobile-app-tracker, screen-time

I had to create an Android application which will work on  screen time of different applications. I can't find any way to get the screen time data. There is an app digital wellbeing for Android application but I can't find its api. So is there any way to track screen time or export the data of digital wellbeing application. Either of them will be helpful for me.

I had tried to search for different options. I came across with Google fit api but it gives me step count only whereas I need to work with screen time data.

Answer (score 0):

UsageStatsManager

Provides access to device usage history and statistics. Usage data is aggregated into time intervals: days, weeks, months, and years.

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiVnbqPrZWEAxVhLbkGHfQuCIoQFnoECA8QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fapp%2Fusage%2FUsageStatsManager&usg=AOvVaw1w3SpPCH0PLES1KqmXftzi&opi=89978449

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).